# How to align training and test set when using pandas `get_dummies` with `drop_first=True`?

Tags: python, machine-learning, sklearn-pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have a data set from telecom company having lots of categorical features. I used the `pandas.get_dummies` method to convert them into one hot encoded format with `drop_first=True` option. Now how can I use the predict function, test input data needs to be encoded in the same way, as the drop_first=True option also dropped some columns, how can I ensure that encoding takes place in similar fashion.

Data set shape before encoding : `(7043, 21)`
Data set shape after encoding : `(7043, 31)`

Answer (score 1):

When **not** using `drop_first=True` you have two options:

1. Perform the one-hot encoding before splitting the data in training and test set. (Or combine the data sets, perform the one-hot encoding, and split the data sets again).
2. Align the data sets after one-hot encoding: an inner join removes the features that are not present in one of the sets (they would be useless anyway). `train, test = train.align(test, join='inner', axis=1)`

You noted (correctly) that method 2 may not do what you expect because you are using `drop_first=True`. So you are left with method 1.